# How to get the file path for a file in google drive for use in colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I need the file path for a file stored in Google drive, so I can access it from a Google colab notebook.

E.g.

```
my_dat = ZipFile('/content/drive/MyDrive/some/file/structure/dat.zip', 'r')
```

Is there a quick way to "copy as path" or otherwise get the file path to the clipboard as quickly as possible from google drive?

My current method is to manually type up the file path, which is ***very*** tedious when doing it repeatedly for files deep down in directories. Basically all I need is a way to quickly and easily have 'MyDrive/some/file/structure/dat.zip' on my clipboard (e.g. similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53355510/5783745)), just without manually typing it.

Comment: Best way of going about that would do a file.get searching for your file and then step your way up the parents.  There is no quick way to do this.

Comment: @DaImTo I appreciate it, and wasn’t even aware I could do that. That’s really great because the path of some files I worked with contained visually ambiguous numbers of spaces (don’t ask me why) but that made manually writing the path a painful exercise. Please feel free to make your comment an answer if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 4):

I made my own library to make it easier.

```
!pip install kora
from kora.drive import get_path
p = get_path(file_id)
```

Comment: That’s awesome! For noobies, how does one find the file id?

Comment: I assume you already have it from your link to the file that is shared to you. So, what do you have to start with? If you already have the path, I made another function to get its file_id.

Comment: From a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0l6No313QAhY3ZiVHFTeVpsTms, its ID is 0B0l6No313QAhY3ZiVHFTeVpsTms

Comment: Ah I see. It is a zip file sitting in my google drive. It's not a public file though. (was uploaded by me, so not shared). How do you get to the 'drive.google.com/file/d/0B0l6No313QAhY3ZiVHFTeVpsTms' style link? For me, I navigate to the directory, and it has a 'https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/sdlfkjsldkfjskdfj' type link, but I can't seem to get a /file/d/ link? When I click on a file, it simply previews it without changing the url in the url bar.

Comment: I select the zip file. Then click the 3-dot menu on the top right. Then select "open in new windows". The new tab then has a /file/d/ URL.

Comment: I don't think I get the same options as you: https://imgur.com/a/4Qo5Qmh

Comment: I was using my ipad. On computer, you can right click the zip file and select "get link".

Answer (score 2):

The best way or really the only way I know of doing this using the Google drive api would be to use the

[file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method, this will return a field called parents.  Once you get the parent id you can then do a file get on the parent and continue up until the parent is root.  Its going to mean a lot of calls but its the only way I have found to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file path of a Google document with Apps Script

```js
function filePath() {
  var fileId = 'file ID string goes here';
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents();
  var parent;
  var pathString = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName() ;
  while (parents.hasNext()){
      parent = parents.next();
      pathString = parent.getName() + ">" + pathString;
      parents = parent.getParents()
  }
  Logger.log(pathString)
}
```

In this example, just copy the file ID from the URL and paste it into the code.  The example includes the file name at the end.  You can change the separator to whatever you need.